# ionic-angular components.core.scss error

Tags: angularjs

Just starting with Ionic 2. My first app fails with error:

> > Error: Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.
> >            on line 34 of node_modules/ionic-angular/components.core.scss
> >       @import "fonts/ionicons";

Anyone encountered this problem and knows how to solve it? Would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: That's a Sass error?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution for this:
One of the dependencies has updated (one that is related to sass). In order to fix this issue without changing the files under node-modules is to use **specific versions** for gulp-sass and node-sass. Use the following commands:

```
npm install gulp-sass@2.2.0
npm install node-sass@3.4.2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the best answer :)

Answer (score 4):

In the current beta (`v2.0.0-beta.5`) combined with Sass `Sass 3.4.13`  there seems to be a bug with an `@import` inside an `@if`. This is not allowed.

Comment out the @if structure in `node_modules/iconic_angular/components.core.scss` to look like this:

```
$ionicons: true !default;
// @if ($ionicons) {
  @import "fonts/ionicons";
// }
```

On top of that there seems to be an issue with some declarations in the Sass file for windows. If you don't need Windows for now change the sass include defintion in `node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/index.js` to read (so removing the include for windows).

```
...
  src: 'app/theme/app.+(ios|md).scss', 
...
```

Comment: There is any solution without changing files under node_modules folder?

Comment: If someone else is wondering in which index.js wp has to be removed, it's: node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/index.js

Comment: @atx, you're right. I'll edit my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This bug fixed in ionic "2.0.0-beta.6" version. You can update or check this commit [fix saas errors](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/219059c)

Comment: I had to manually change my package.json to beta.6 but it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to `node_modules/ionic-angular/components.core.scss` and set the variable (`$ionicons`) to `false`.