# error on ionic serve in ionic-angular components.core.scss

Tags: ionic2

On ionic serve I get this error:

> Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins. on line 34 of node_modules/ionic-angular/components.core.scss
>   @import "fonts/ionicons";

Anyone knows how to fix this? Would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: could you post more of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I ran into this issue too... It's due to a change in some dependencies see an explanation here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6258

There is even an answer here on SO:

[ionic-angular components.core.scss error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757738/ionic-angular-components-core-scss-error/36765721?noredirect=1#comment61154821_36765721)

The ionic team states, that they have fixed it by now. So just creating a new porject should fix this issue!